# What is the host for the remote wordpress database connection?

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I have been going through various threads on this but none seem to answer my question. I am trying to connect to a remote database using cPanel and phpmyadmin, however I am not sure I am understanding it the right way around.

1) I have created my user login:dbadmin/pw: Tst1234 in MySQL® Databases un cPanel and assigned my users with all rights to the demo_database

2) I have gone into Remote MySQL and added my **LOCAL machine's IP** address as a connection with an wildcart "%"

3) I am now trying to find what the remote host because my default wordpress config.php file has **LOCALHOST** in the following settings

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'demo_database');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'dbadmin');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Tst1234');

/** MySQL hostname */
**define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');**

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

This is obviously not right because I get:
*Error establishing a database connection*

As an error. But how do I find what is the **remote demo_database host** address in order to configure wordpress? I have checked on my "remote" phpmyadmin I in the database server details all I can find is:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket

Something is wrong with this picture.How do I add my "remote" database host to my "local" config file?

Thanks

Comment: You'll get the address of the database server in your cPanel.

Comment: Where exactly? I am looking on cpanel phpmyadmin which just tells me Localhost, I have gone into MySQL® Databases and it doesn't tell me anything about the database address.

Comment: Have you created the database? WordPress will not do this for you.

Comment: How did you do this one: "I have gone into Remote MySQL". This MySQL server host, where you create a user, is the host you are looking for. How did you connect to "Remote MySQL" to create users? But keep in mind - Remote MySQL server must have opened FireWall rules for connection.